# Effect of Green's function on aerodynamic lift and drag

Tags: complex-analysis, fluid-dynamics, greens-function

I am trying to determine the effect of inserting a Green's function on the lift and drag exerted on a body inmersed in an inviscid, incompressible and irrotational flow in 2D. One concrete example is the vortex $\vec{v}=\Gamma\nabla \theta/2\pi$ where $\theta$ is the polar angle or the point source $\vec{v}=Q\nabla Log(r)/2\pi$.
By placing it close to a body immersed in fluid flow, it alters the flow and hence the forces on the body. The question is how to determine the new forces.

Comment: Expanding on the question, my first hunch is to compute the force in the case of a circular cylinder. This case is posed as an exercise in many text books (force exerted by a vortex or a source on a circular cylinder inmersed in a free-stream, which is solved by the method of images and Blasius theorem, see for example Milne-Thomson "Theoretical Hydrodynamics"), but the question is whether this is the correct solution, or whether far-field boundary conditions or some other considerations play any role.

Comment: The purpose of this is to compute the analytic solution to the incompressible Euler equations for case of irrotational flow following the ideas in https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/gilesm/files/AIAA-97-1850.pdf   Using the approach explained in that paper and with the strategy outlined above I have been able to obtain a valid solution for the adjoint solution corresponding to aerodynamic drag, but not for lift, so I pressume that my reasoning is somehow flawed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the procedure I was using was correct, but I had missed the contribution of the Kutta condition (extra lift that has to be added to prevent singularities at sharp trailing edges). With that additional contribution, analytic adjoint solutions can be computed as shown in

https://arxiv.org/abs/2201.08128